# Will forcing a gas through an aluminum foam cool or heat it up

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, thermal-conductivity

Metal foams are known to be porous and interconnected when in open cell form, will forcing a gas stream through the network heat it up due to restrictions and friction or cool it down due to large surface area and high thermal conductivity if there exist a temperature difference of about 270 K.

Comment: Depends on the gas. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect

Comment: Nitrogen gas at 300°C

Comment: That is below the inversion temperature of nitrogen at atmospheric pressure (621 K), so the gas should cool. But I have no experience with this.

Comment: By forcing through I meant at great pressure, does that factor in?

Comment: I know this isn't exactly my question but maybe you can answer this. I've been exploring adiabatic expansion and Joule-Thomson cooling for a while now and that got me curious: if by expanding a gas or throttling it it cools, where does the heat energy go since the system is adiabatic.